# Play Audio from Microphone through Speakers

Tags: java, audio, signal-processing, microphone, speaker

I'm wondering how I can, in Java, preferably using `DataLine` capture audio from the microphone, and play it directly to the speakers, even if there is some delay.

Basically, I want to be able to take the audio from the microphone, store a buffer of a finite number of samples, be able to modify each sample in some way, and play it back out through the speakers with as little time for each sample between being recorded and played. Sort of like writing a Java program to use my computer as an effects pedal; is this possible?(Assuming I already know how to modify the samples). Just to be clear, I **don't** want to record a finite number of samples from the microphone, stop recording, modify, then play; I want it to be continuously recording and playing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of reading from a `TargetDataLine` into a byte buffer and then writing it to a `SourceDataLine` in a loop indefinitely.

The resulting latency will be highly dependent on the size of audio buffer you use. The larger your buffer the larger the latency.

Take a look at the AudioLoop example [here](https://github.com/leif81/jsresources-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsresources/audioloop/AudioLoop.java).

Comment: Looks like jsresources.org is no longer a valid link.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner Ok i've updated the link. Fortunately I cached a copy on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks! This is valuable information. Am very glad to see it available.

Comment: Your answer should have been selected. This code by Matthias is solid. I've seen other work of his in audio, too, all good.